# Quando se deve usar 'var' no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Sempre fico em dúvida nos projetos se coloco `var` antes de dar um valor a uma variavel ou não pois ambos funcionam (eu acho). Alguém sabe explicar o motivo de usar ou não? Qual a convenção ou boa prática a ser seguida?

É uma pergunta boba eu acho, mas como nunca estudei JavaScript gostaria de saber.

Comment: Não é uma pergunta boba não, pelo contrário. Na verdade, considerando a frequência com que a gente vê código JavaScript "poluído" com declarações globais de variáveis, é uma pergunta bastante relevante!

Comment: @Maniero qual seria o seu critério usado para determinar que essa pergunta não teve atenção suficiente?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam O meu estritamente pessoal. Quem está dando a recompensa pode fazê-lo onde quiser. Não é requisito ter motivo a pessoa gastar sua reputação para destacar algo que acha que deve.

Comment: @Maniero apenas estranhei, já tinha visto você oferecer recompensas para recompensar uma resposta existente. Não entendi o motivo dessa, pensei que de repente queria alguma resposta atualizada com `const` e `let`, mas não tinha certeza

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam essa é sobre o `var` muito usuário ainda não usa.

Comment: Seguinte por ser 'var' quando e compilado o codigo, ela tem preferencia de leitura.. Var oi = 0; ela sera interpretada primeira do que, oi = 1;

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> **AVISO**
>
> Esta resposta foi escrita antes de `let` e `const` estarem disponíveis em todos os navegadores. O princípio geral da resposta ainda é válido: sempre declare suas variáveis. Porém, atualmente é recomendado utilizar `let` ou `const` no lugar de `var`.

Sempre é recomendado usar a palavra chave `var` pois torna a variável local, caso contrario ela vira global. Isso evita conflitos, variável corrompida, torna o código menos vulnerável a acesso via barra de endereço.

`javascript:count = 0`, um código semelhante a essa zerava a contagem do rapishare na hora do fazer o download, porém como tinha uma validação side server ele não deixa baixar o arquivo em um periodo curto

exemplo de variavel exposta: (testei isso no chrome, o firefox acabou mudando bastante a politica de javascript se não me engano apartir da versão 25 então o exemplo não vai funcionar)

Esse código foi retirado de um site real.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var xtx=20; // linha original
    function IniciaRegressivo() {
        if (xtx > 0) {
            document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML =
           '<div class="protetor-botao"><a>Aguarde '+ xtx +' segundos</a></div>';
            xtx = xtx - 1;
            setTimeout("IniciaRegressivo();", 1000);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML = 
            '<div class="protetor-botao">
            <a href="javascript:download();">Fazer Download</a></div>';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="IniciaRegressivo();">

<div name="botao" id="botao"></div>
</html>
```

Na barra de endereço do navegador digite esse 'código'(digite pelo menos `javascript:` e depois cole o resto)

```
javascript:xtx=0;IniciaRegressivo();
```

veja o resultado.

Agora modifique a linha:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var xtx=20; // linha original
```

para:

```
if(typeof(xtx) == "undefined"){
   xtx = 80; //variavel local da função IniciaRegressivo() certo?
}
```

de um ctrl+f5 e teste novamente.

Comment: Sua resposta foi realmente muito útil para mim! +1

Comment: Me parece também, que variáveis globais no JS não funcionam no IE8...não que ele faça diferença na minha vida...mas...

Answer (score 36):

> **AVISO**
>
> Esta resposta foi escrita antes de `let` e `const` estarem disponíveis em todos os navegadores. O princípio geral da resposta ainda é válido: sempre declare suas variáveis. Porém, atualmente é recomendado utilizar `let` ou `const` no lugar de `var`.

O `var` é fundamental para distinguir variáveis locais de globais. Sem ele, todas as variáveis serão globais – pior, serão globais *implícitas*, já que o código não deixa claro o escopo.

Isso é sério o suficiente para ser proibido no modo estrito da linguagem:

```
function teste() {
    "use strict";
    x = 10;
}
teste(); // ReferenceError
```

Tenha sempre em mente que cada função cria um novo escopo em JavaScript. Portanto, variáveis *diferentes* mas com o mesmo nome podem existir dentro e fora da função.

Compare:

```
var x = 10;
function alteraGlobal() {
    x = 20;
}
alteraGlobal();
alert(x); // alerta 20
```

Versus:

```
var x = 10;
function alteraLocal() {
    var x = 20;  // este x é outro, local!
}
alteraLocal();
alert(x); // alerta 10
```

Isso é o básico que se precisa entender sobre escopo e `var` em JavaScript. Para a sutileza de usar ou não `var` para criar, propositalmente, uma variável global, veja a [resposta do Anthony Accioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript/2519#2519).

Answer (score 27):

> **AVISO**
>
> Esta resposta foi escrita antes de `let` e `const` estarem disponíveis em todos os navegadores. O princípio geral da resposta ainda é válido: sempre declare suas variáveis. Porém, atualmente é recomendado utilizar `let` ou `const` no lugar de `var`.

## O que diz a documentação?

Como definido pela [documentação da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> The scope of a variable declared with var is the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside a function, the global scope (which is bound to the global object).
> Using var outside a function is optional; assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly declares it as a global variable (it is now a property of the global object). **The difference is that a declared variable is a non-configurable property of the global object while an undeclared is configurable**.

Em tradução livre:

> O escopo em que a variável var é declarada com o var é definido a partir do encapsulamento da função em que é declarado ou, para variáveis declarada fora de funções, o escopo global (que é o "limite" do objecto global).
> Utilizar o var fora de uma função é opcional; atribuir um valor para uma variável não declarada, implicitamente declara a variável como global (passa a ser uma propriedade do objeto global). **A diferença é que uma variável declarada é uma propriedade não-configurável do objeto global, enquanto uma variável não-declarada é configurável**.

## Qual a influência disso?

As implicações podem ser obtidas do exemplo encontrado no mesmo [link da documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) fornecido anteriormente.

```
var a = 1;
b = 2;

delete this.a; // Lança um TypeError no "strict mode". Senão falha silenciosamente 
delete this.b;

console.log(a, b); //Lança um ReferenceError. Como a propriedade 'b' não existe no objeto global, b deixa de ser uma variável.
```

Por isso, é recomendado **sempre** utilizar o `var` quando for declarar uma variável interna a uma função, pois atribuir um valor sem declarar a variável dentro de uma função, geralmente pode causar erros e, por esse motivo, o [strict mode da ECMAScript 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope%2FStrict_mode) lança um erro.

Answer (score 21):

> **AVISO**
>
> Esta resposta foi escrita antes de `let` e `const` estarem disponíveis em todos os navegadores. O princípio geral da resposta ainda é válido: sempre declare suas variáveis. Porém, atualmente é recomendado utilizar `let` ou `const` no lugar de `var`.

Vou fazer uma transcrição (com leves adaptações em *itálico*) de [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1471738/664577) do usuário [kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax) no SOE que, na minha opinião, é  a melhor referência sobre o assunto que temos (superando a resposta aceita para a pergunta original no SOE).

---

**Existe uma diferença *entre declarações com ou sem o uso de `var`***.

`var x = 1` **declara a variável** `x` no escopo atual (também conhecido como contexto de execução). Se a declaração aparece dentro de uma função - uma variável local é declarada; se aparece no escopo global - uma variável global é declarada.

`x = 1`, por outro lado, é apenas uma atribuição de propriedade. O *interpretador* tenta primeiro resolver `x` contra a cadeia de escopo. Se ele encontra *`x`* em qualquer lugar da cadeida de escopo, ele faz uma atribuição; se ele não encontra `x`, somente então **ele cria a propriedade `x` em um objeto global** (que é um objeto no nível superior de uma cadeia de  chamada *e.g., `window`*).

Agora, perceba que *o comando `x = 1`* não declara uma variável global, ele cria uma propriedade global.

A diferença entre as duas é sútil e pode ser confusa a não ser que você entenda que **declarações de variáveis também criam propriedades** (apenas em um *[Variable Object](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/)* [*link meu*]) e que toda propriedade em Javascript (bem, ECMAScript) tem certas *flags* que descrevem suas propriedades - ReadOnly, DontEnum and DontDelete.

Como a declaração de variáveis cria propriedades com a *flag* DontDelete, a diferença entre `var x = 1` e `x = 1` (quando executada no escopo global) é que a primeira - declaração de variável - cria uma propriedade não deletável, e a última não. Como consequência, propriedades criadas através dessa atribuição implícita podem ser deletadas do objeto global, enquanto as primeiras - *aquelas* criadas via declaração da variável - não podem.

Mas isso é apenas teoria e **na prática existem ainda mais diferenças entre as duas**,  devido a vários erros nas implementações (com os do IE).

Espero que tudo faça sentido : )

**[Atualização 16/12/2010]**

No ES5 (ECMAScript 5; a recentemente padronizada quinta edição da linguagem) há um assim chamado "modo estrito" — um modo opcional da linguagem que altera ligeiramente o comportamento de atribuições não declaradas. Dentro do modo estrito, a atribuição de um identificador não declarado é *considerado um* **ReferenceError**. A justificativa para isso é identificar as atribuições acidentais, impedindo a criação de propriedades globais indesejadas. Alguns dos navegadores mais recentes já começaram a suportar o modo estrito. Veja, por exemplo, [a tabela de compatibilidade *no blog do kangax*](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table).

**Notas minhas**:

- Já temos o ES6 no forno, previsto para se tornar uma padrão em Dezembro de 2014. Deixei a nota de atualização (datada de 2010) apenas para explicar o comportamento do modo estrito.
- NO ES5 a noção de *Variable Object* foi substituída pela de [*Lexical Environments*](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2) (não sou corajoso o suficiente para tentar traduzir nenhum dos dois conceitos por pensar em pelo menos 3 traduções diferentes para cada).

Comment: O kangax tem um post no blog dele onde explica isso tudo com ainda mais detalhes: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 12):

> **AVISO**
>
> Esta resposta foi escrita antes de `let` e `const` estarem disponíveis em todos os navegadores. O princípio geral da resposta ainda é válido: sempre declare suas variáveis. Porém, atualmente é recomendado utilizar `let` ou `const` no lugar de `var`.

Creio que a [melhor resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it#answer-1470494) que já vi ate hoje e que seja bem simples esta no próprio SO.

#### Transcrição

Se você está no escopo global então não há nenhuma diferença.

Se você estiver em uma função, `var` vai criar uma variável local, a não utilização de `var` fara com que ele procure a variável pelos escopos a cima dele ate chegar do escopo global, só então, se ele não encontrar a variável era criá-la (no escopo global).

```
// Estas estão no escopo global
var foo = 1;
bar = 2;

function()
{
    var foo = 1; // Local
    bar = 2;     // Global

    // Execute uma função anonima
    (function()
    {
        var wibble = 1; // Local
        foo = 2; // Herda do escopo acima (criada na função)
        moo = 3; // Global
    }())
}
```

Se você não está fazendo uma atribuição então você precisa usar o `var`:

```
var x; // Declara x
```

#### Obs

Todas as respostas a cima estão corretas, apenas salientei esta, pois me parece a mais simples.

Answer (score 10):

> **AVISO**
>
> Esta resposta foi escrita antes de `let` e `const` estarem disponíveis em todos os navegadores. O princípio geral da resposta ainda é válido: sempre declare suas variáveis. Porém, atualmente é recomendado utilizar `let` ou `const` no lugar de `var`.

Javascript é uma linguagem ampla, porque você pode fazer quase todas as coisas que você quer em uma página da Web, apenas através de criação de funções e encontrar maneiras de fazer.

Posso dizer que o JavaScript não é uma linguagem segura, porque você pode facilmente acessar a maior parte das variáveis ​​e funções, ler e saber como ele funciona, apenas acessando o arquivo *.js, incluído na página.

**Meu Pensamento:** Alguns modificadores de acesso foram criados para usar em javascript devido a necessidades, porque o JavaScript não "se transporta" à outros lugares (páginas), a menos que você use uma variável de sessão.

**E sobre isso, alguns modificadores conhecidos:**

```java
private
protected
public
```

Eu posso te dizer que eu sei que alguns modificadores do javascript têm alguma semelhança com eles, que são:

**Local:**

```js
var Variavel = 0;
```

Automaticamente, esta é convertida em uma variável Inteiro(Integer), porque ele está recebendo um valor Inteiro(Integer), e também, esta é uma variável local por causa do modificador `var` que declara esta variável de uma maneira que você não pode acessar o valor dela, a menos que você esteja dentro da mesma função que essa variável foi declarada.

**Exemplo:**

**Se você declarar estas funções desta forma, com modificadores padrão:**

```js
function conflito(){
  i = 2;
  mudarI();
  alert(i);
}
function mudarI(){
  i = 0;
}
```

Neste caso, o `i` é a mesma variável para as duas funções.

Então, se você executar `conflito()` , você vai receber um alerta de que resulta `0`.

**MAS, se você declarar `i` usando o modificador `var`:**

```js
function conflito(){
  var i = 2;
  mudarI();
  alert(i);
}
function mudarI(){
  var i = 0;
}
```

Neste caso, você tem duas variáveis `​​i`, porque elas estão restritas ao uso apenas dentro de sua função, por isso, se você executar `conflito();` agora, você receberá um alerta com valor de `2`.

**Variável pertencente ao Método:**

```js
this.Variable = "a";
```

Esta variável é automaticamente um String, porque ele está recebendo um valor String, Provavelmente você já sabe o que este modificador faz, mas, vou tentar explicar com o meu ponto de vista, isto é, esta variável está vindo da SuperClass ou seja, que pode ser chamado de uma classe , ou em outras palavras , a classe "pai".

**Um exemplo:**

```js
function TClass()
{
  this.getVar = function()
  {
    try
    {
      return "test";
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  this.alertVar = function()
  {
    try
    {
      alert(this.getVar());
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      alert('erro');
    }
  }
}
var $Class = new TClass();
```

Como você pode ver acima , eu criei uma classe `TClass` e algumas variáveis ​​que contêm funções dentro (javascript closure) e adicionei o modificador nelas. Para torná-las vinculadas ao `TClass` e, como você vê na função `alertVar()`, se executar `alert(this.getVar())`, ele executa a função que é do `TClass` neste contexto.

**E esta parte:**

```js
var $Class = new TClass();
```

Eu estou criando a classe como você provavelmente já sabe, para ter acesso a seus métodos, fazendo isso é possível executar, para testar:

```js
$Class.alertVar();
```

Resultando um alert contendo "test", como você pode ver :

[image: alert contendo teste]

Note que você não pode acessar os métodos `TClass` de outra forma, você só pode acessá-lo se criar a instância da classe e acessar por ela.

Espero que você tenha entendido a usabilidade deste modificador.

**Variáveis Globais:**

```js
window.Variable = true;
```

Automaticamente o javascript declara esta variável como um boolean, porque ele está recebendo um valor booleano. O modificador `window`, como ele mesmo diz, você pode acessá-lo no momento que você está na janela(window), porque variáveis JavaScript ​​quando declaradas, elas vão para o DOM da janela, veja o que é DOM:

**DOM(Document Object Model):** O DOM, é uma multi-plataforma que representa a forma como estão organizados as marcações(markup's) HTML, XHTML, e XML lido pelo navegador que você está usando. Em outras palavras, se você acessar o DOM você pode ver cada Propriedade, todas as variáveis​​, ou qualquer coisa que está declarada no navegador no momento.

Diferente de outras variáveis​​, as variáveis ​​da janela pode ter atribuído um outro valor e acessar o valor atual, não importando de onde você esteja acessando, dentro de uma função ou não, dentro de um arquivo *.js ou não.

**Exemplo de Global(window):**

Execute no evento `onLoad` de uma página um código que declara uma variável de janela(window), ou declare usando console do navegador mesmo:

```js
window.Variable = true;
```

Em seguida, adicione um arquivo JS que contém esta função, ou declare apenas por executar o código no console do navegador:

```js
function testGlobalVar(){
  if (Variable)
    alert("funciona!");
}
```

Quando você executa `testGlobalVar()` você receberá o alerta, mas é só porque você declarou como 'janela(window)' em caso contrário, não vai executar.

**Modificador padrão do Javascript:**

```js
Variavel = 0.5;
```

Automaticamente esta variável é declarada como Float porque está recebendo um valor Float. Eu não sei se você já sabe, mas variáveis javascript ​​declaradas como de costume (sem modificadores), tem um modificador de padrão que faz com que a variável fique semelhante a variáveis ​​da janela , mas você não pode acessá-la de qualquer lugar que esteja, mas na maioria dos casos, você pode acessá-la, particularmente, eu não sei todos os casos que você não pode acessá-la, mas eu sei que você não pode quando você carregou um arquivo *.js e foi declarado dentro dele. Só se você executar uma função que a declara, para ela ir para o DOM e depois disso tentar acessar.

Todavia, eu vejo que você quer saber sobre o `var` em questão, mas eu te dei uma explicação geral de todos os modificadores que conheço(acredito que são todos), para seu conhecimento fique mais amplo e você tenha um entendimento melhor sobre o modificador em questão.

Espero que você entenda o que estou dizendo .

Ah, e se você ficou confuso quando viu uma função dentro de uma variável , estude **Javascript Closures**, você vai entender depois de um tempo :).

Comment: Muito bom. Esse conteúdo me agregou bastante!

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas o JavaScript só possui um tipo numérico (Nunber), tanto para valores inteiros como decimais, sendo assim, `1 ===1.0` é verdadeiro