# Dificuldade em armazenar propriedade em objeto no Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dificuldade (que provavelmente é bem boba) em armazenar um valor em uma propriedade de um objeto em Javascript. Já fiz algo parecido recentemente utilizando `this.propriedade = valor` dentro da função "construtora" e não tive problemas em reutilizar o valor em uma função definida como `Objeto.prototype.nome_funcão".

Porém, nesse exemplo ([disponível no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luigivieira/K6u2b/3/)) uma propriedade (`this.m_oClickCallback`) não é visível na função de tratamento do clique do mouse (`MyButton.prototype.handleClick`), gerando a seguinte exceção quando o botão é clicado:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method
>   'm_oClickCallback'

Eu imagino que provavelmente o erro se deve a algo bem bobo, mas não estou conseguindo enxergar o que é.

Aqui está o html do exemplo que eu preparei:

```html
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600">
        O seu navegador não suporta HTML5. (<i>Your browser does not support HTML5.</i>)
    </canvas>
</body>
```

E o código Javascript:

```js
(function() {

    // Objeto de botão customizado
    var MyButton = function(sLabel, sColor, oClickCallback) {
        // Chama o initialize do objeto protótipo (createjs.Container)
        this.initialize();

        // Armazena a referência para o callback do evento de click
        this.m_oClickCallback = oClickCallback;

        // Cria o conteúdo do botão
        var oText = new createjs.Text(sLabel, "40px Arial", "#ffffff");
        oText.textBaseline = "top";
        oText.textAlign = "center";

        var iWidth = oText.getMeasuredWidth() + 30;
        var iHeight = oText.getMeasuredHeight() + 20;

        var oBackground = new createjs.Shape();
        oBackground.name = "Background";
        oBackground.graphics.beginFill(sColor).drawRoundRect(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, 10);

        oText.x = iWidth / 2;
        oText.y = 10;

        this.addChild(oBackground, oText);

        // Captura o evento de click        
        this.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
    }  

    // Define o protótipo
    MyButton.prototype = new createjs.Container();

    // Função de tratamento do click no botão. Invoca o callback armazenado.
    MyButton.prototype.handleClick = function(oEvent) {
        this.m_oClickCallback(oEvent.target);
    } 

    // Atribui o objeto ao escopo global de "window"
    window.MyButton = MyButton;
}());

// Função de inicialização. Cria o botão no onload do corpo da página.
function init() {
    g_oStage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");
    var oButton = new MyButton("Olá mundo!", "red", function() { alert("Funciona!"); });
    g_oStage.addChild(oButton);
    g_oStage.update();
}
```

EDIT: a ideia é armazenar a propriedade de forma que ela seja diferenciada entre cada nova instância do objeto (como se fosse mesmo um atributo privado ou público de uma classe em outras linguagens). Soluções em que a propriedade é compartilhada (como se fosse estática) não são o interesse da pergunta.

EDIT2:

Descobri que no createjs.Container há uma propriedade chamada `this.mouseChildren` que quando desabilitada faz com que o objeto `target` enviado no *payload* dos eventos de mouse seja diretamente o objeto `MyButton` ao invés de seus componentes (o texto ou o *shape* colorido de fundo). Usando essa propriedade e o objeto `target` eu consigo resolver o problema da seguinte forma (veja [esse novo JSFiddle de exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/luigivieira/K6u2b/8/), agora com duas instâncias de botão):

```js
//. . .

// Faz o target dos eventos ser diretamente o objeto MyButton, ao invés do texto
// ou do background nele inclusos
this.mouseChildren = false;

//. . .

// Função de tratamento do click no botão. Invoca o callback armazenado.
MyButton.prototype.handleClick = function(oEvent) {
    oEvent.target.clickCallback(oEvent.target);
}
```

Logando o `this` no console, eu percebi que ele se é de fato o objeto `window`. Por isso não funcionava o código. Não adicionei essa conclusão como uma resposta porque ainda me resta a dúvida de por que a função de tratamento do clique do mouse não é invocada no escopo do botão e sim da janela do navegador. Alguém sabe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nem sempre `this` irá se referir ao objeto que você está criando: quando você usa `this.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);` o valor de `this` deixa de ser o objeto e passa ser o escopo global, geralmente `window`.

Esse problema pode ser solucionado de várias maneiras. Não vou entrar muito em detalhes pois [esse tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/) (em inglês) aborta detalhadamente esse assunto, mas baseando-se nele você resolveria seu problema simplesmente fazendo isso:

```js
/* remova */ this.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
/* insira */ this.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick.bind(this));
```

Comment: Tá ai, boa resposta. Valeu pelo link de referência. :)

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que eu vi no seu código, em nenhum momento você declara o `m_oClickCallBack` dentro do escopo de `MyButton`. É necessário dentro do `MyButton`acrescentar a linha:

```js
var m_oClickCallBack;
```

Para mais informações, veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript).

Comment: Sim, é verdade, mas fiz assim porque eu entendi que usando o `this.m_oClickCallback` eu estaria criando uma "propriedade pública" (veja esse link: http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS.html). De todas as formas, usando `var m_oClickCallBack = oClickCallBack` eu obtenho o erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: m_oClickCallback is not defined`.

Answer (score 1):

Luiz Vieira o problema é que o ECMAScript 5.1 (se não me engano) coloca a variável `this` como escopo global, o mais indicado é você substituir a linha

```
this.m_oClickCallback = oClickCallback;
```

Por

```
MyButton.m_oClickCallback = oClickCallback;
```

E na hora de chamar o `m_oClickCallback` você pode fazer assim

```
this.MyButton.m_oClickCallback(oEvent.target);
```

Comment: Hum, funciona. Mas qual é a "explicação" nesse caso? :) Além disso, fazendo assim a variável `m_oClickCallback` não vai compartilhar o valor entre todas as instâncias de `MyButton`?

Comment: Na verdade quando você coloca um MyButton.m_oClickCallback o m_oClickCallback se torna uma **propriedade** do **MyButton**

Comment: Como eu imaginava, a sua sugestão é de uma propriedade definida no objeto-base (algo como se fosse a 'classe', honestamente não sei como me referir a isso em Javascript) e não na instância dele. Tanto que nesse exemplo vc nota que apesar de funcionar os dois botões invocam O MESMO callback (e não é essa a intenção): http://jsfiddle.net/luigivieira/K6u2b/5/

Answer (score 1):

Olha, consegui fazer funcionar veja este exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6u2b/4/)

Mas tive que alterar seu código, talvez você não aceite a minha solução, porém, ela é funcional, o que eu fiz foi:

Nesta parte da criação:

```
    // Armazena a referência para o callback do evento de click
    this.m_oClickCallback = oClickCallback;
```

Modifiquei para:

```
    // Armazena a referência para o callback do evento de click
    m_oClickCallback = oClickCallback;
```

E aonde você atribui o evento ao botão:

```
// Função de tratamento do click no botão. Invoca o callback armazenado.
MyButton.prototype.handleClick = function(oEvent) {
      this.m_oClickCallback(oEvent.target);
}
```

Modifiquei para:

```
// Função de tratamento do click no botão. Invoca o callback armazenado.
MyButton.prototype.handleClick = function(oEvent) {
  m_oClickCallback(oEvent.target);
}
```

Não creio que seja a melhor solução, porém, funciona.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu acho que nesse caso a variável está sendo declarada globalmente, e por isso funciona. Mas se eu tiver dois objetos `MyButton` usando a mesma variável global isso vai ser problemático, não é?

Comment: Vou testar com duas istâncias, e jaja te falo, mas acredito que realmente estaria sendo global.

Comment: Embora globais às vezes sejam necessárias, é possível evitá-las neste caso. Criar uma global dessa maneira, sem antes declará-la com `var` no escopo global, não é uma prática recomendada, pois caso isso cause um bug (como o que o @LuizVieira citou), ele pode ficar difícil de identificar. Sugestão: experimente programar no "strict mode" do JavaScript, que lança uma exceção se você faz uma coisa dessas. É um bom caminho para desenvolver o aprendizado da linguagem sem cair em algumas armadilhas que ela, por razões históricas, possui.