# Utilizar valor de uma função

Tags: javascript, funções

Quero utilizar o valor dentro de uma função fora da mesma. Tenho a variável global, e como é um variavel que nunca é o mesmo, que apresenta-lo. Testei isto, e so funcionou uma vez com o valor undifined, porque a função nao foi executada.

```
var circle_x;

function deselectElement(evt){
  if(selectedElement != 0){
    selectedElement.parentNode.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
    selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
    selectedElement = 0;
    dx=evt.clientX;
    //objet 1
    if(selectedLineX == 1){

        circle_x=currentX;

    }

  }

}

alert(circle_x);
```

Comment: Provavelmente não funcionou porque é extremamente difícil administrar variáveis globais: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32252/101. E se não for possível pegar a informação que você que, ou seja, se não entrar nesse `if`, a função deve retornar o que?

Comment: A função serve para deselecionar um objeto SVG. Quando largo do cursor.

Comment: Pode mostrar mais do seu código? há variaveis aí que não dá para ver de onde vêm.

Comment: A resposta ajudou? Acha que deve aceitá-la?

Answer (score 3):

Elimine a variável global. Provavelmente não funcionou porque é extremamente difícil administrar variáveis globais. Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32252/101).

```
function deselectElement(evt){
    if(selectedElement != 0){
        selectedElement.parentNode.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
        selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
        selectedElement = 0;
        dx = evt.clientX;
        //objet 1
        if(selectedLineX == 1){
            circle_x = currentX;
            return circle_x;
        }
    }
    return null; //não me parece coisa boa mas tem que retornar algo, pelo menos assim está explícito    
}

var circle_x = deselectElement(evt);
alert(circle_x);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/EscopeVar.js).

Aqui o código faz a comunicação como deveria, através da entra (parâmetros) e saída (retorno) da função.

Note que você continua tendo variáveis globais. De onde vem o `currentX`? Até os melhores programadores não conseguem gerenciar um código cheio de variáveis globais.

E a variável `dx` não está sendo usada para nada. O código tem algumas coisas esquisitas, mas acho que a dúvida central está respondida. Se não for isto, dê mais detalhes na sua pergunta.