# Variável não declarada

Tags: c, array, variáveis

Está dando erro nas linhas 118, 127, 133, 139...

> 127    20 'vetor' was not declared in this scope

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define tamanho 5

 int pos=0;

struct agenda {

                char nome [40];
                char data_de_nascimento [10];
                char local_onde_mora [10];
                int telefone;
                char numero_matricula[80];
                char nome_pai [50];
                char nome_mae [50];
                char numero_identidade [50];
               }aluno;

int main();
int alterar(struct agenda vetor[]){

 char nomealteracao[100];
 int T=0; 
 int x;

 printf("Informe o nome do aluno a ser alterado:");
 gets(nomealteracao);
 for (x=0; x <= tamanho; x++){
  if(strcmp(vetor[x].nome,nomealteracao)==0){
 printf("Digite o novo nome:");
 gets(vetor[x].nome);
 printf("Data de  nascimento:");
 gets (vetor[x].data_de_nascimento);
 printf("Digite o novo numero da matricula:");
 gets(vetor[x].numero_matricula);
 printf("Digite o novo nome do pai:");
 gets(vetor[x].nome_pai);
 printf("Digite o novo nome da mae:");
 gets(vetor[x].nome_mae);
 printf("Digite o novo numero de identidade:");
 gets(vetor[x].numero_identidade);

   return T;


   }
}
if(T==1) {
 printf("Aluno nao cadastrado.");
 system("cls");
 return 0;
}

}

int  remover(struct agenda vetor[],int *Pos){
     char nome[40];
     int i,x;

     printf("Digite qual o nome do aluno que deseja remover:");
     gets(nome);

     for(i=0;i<=(*Pos);i++){
       if(strcmp (vetor[i].nome, nome)== 0){
          for(x = i + 1; x<= (*Pos); x++){
                vetor[x-1] = vetor[x];
          }
          (*Pos)--;

          break;
          system("cls");
       }
     } 
     main();

     if(i > tamanho){
          printf("Registro inxistente");
          system("cls");
    return 0;

     }
 int main();
}
int cadastrar ( struct agenda vetor[], int *pos){    

    if(*pos==tamanho){
                 main();

} else{
                     printf("Digite o nome: ");
                     gets(vetor[*pos].nome);
                     printf("Digite o numero da matricula: ");
                     gets(vetor[*pos].numero_matricula);
                     (*pos)++;

                     system("cls");

}
main();
}

int main(){

    int x;

    int opc;

    opc=0;


    if (opc== 0){
 printf ("Pesquisa do numero de matricula dos Alunos da Escola Estadual Joao Pereira:\n");
 printf("[1] - Cadastrar Aluno  \n[2] - Remover Aluno \n[3] - Alterar Informacoes \n[4] - Exibir Informacoes do Aluno \n[5] - Sair do Programa \n\n");
     printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
    scanf ("%d",&opc); fflush(stdin);
     system("cls");

  if(opc==1){
 cadastrar (vetor,&pos);
     pos++;
   main();
   system("cls");


    }
    if (opc ==2){

     opc = remover(vetor, &pos );

system("cls");
    }

    if (opc==3){
    opc = alterar(vetor);
    system("cls");
    main();
    }
    if (opc == 4 ){
      for(x = 0; x < pos; x++){
       printf("Nome: %s \n", vetor[x].nome);
       printf("Telefone: %d \n", vetor[x].matricula);

       system("cls"); 
    }
  main();
    }
    if (opc ==5){
     system("pause");
     return 0;
    }
    }


    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Seu código tem vários problemas e como este é um problema bem simples eu imagino que você não está entendendo metade do código que está aí. Resolvendo este problema, você ainda não terá o código funcionando corretamente.

Mas para resolver este problema que você está dizendo será necessário declarar a variável `vetor` antes de usá-la como você fez com outras variáveis:

```
int main() {
    int x;
    int opc = 0;
    agenda vetor[50]; //para ter 50 cadastros no máximo
    ...
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/VarDeclaration.c).

Você precisa organizar melhor seu código, é muito difícil entender o que está acontecendo nele.

Ele está usando [recursão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Isto é a última coisa que você deseja fazer com a função `main()`. Vou pode criar um problema de memória. Você precisa substituir isto por um *loop*. Além de ser muito melhor é mais fácil de trabalhar. Quando você tem que declarar esta função antes de defini-la já dá para perceber que tem algo errado aí.

Você usa muitas [variáveis globais](http://linguagemc.com.br/funcoes-e-escopo-de-variaveis/). [Isto nunca é bom em qualquer linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32252/101).

Colocar um `system("cls");` logo após um `printf()` tem efeito prático de não fazer nada.

A função `gets()` [tem problema de segurança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43001/101) e **nunca** deve ser usado.