# Como criar função modular cujo parâmetro é um operador?

Tags: javascript, operadores, parâmetros, funções

Supomos que eu quero criar uma função que troque o `src` de uma imagem por outra no índice de uma array, assim:

```
var arrayimgs = ["js/img1.jpg","js/img2.jpg","js/img3.jpg"];
var imagem = document.getElementById('imagemslide');
imagem.src = arrayimgs[0];
var count = 0;

function rodarslider(){
    imagem.src = arrayimgs[count+1];
    count++;
}
```

A função acima faz mudar o `src` da imagem subindo o índice do array a cada clique. Isso funciona, mas e se eu quiser usar a mesma função para decrementar o índice e ao invés de ser `count+1` e `count++` ser `count-1` e `count--`?

Eu só consegui criando duas funções porque o Firebug não reconhecia operador como argumento na chamada.

Comment: Por que não passa o "incremento" por parâmetro? Seja ele positivo ou negativo.

Comment: @Wakim Eu tentei mas não deu :/

Comment: Como está chamando sua função?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fgquw9j3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente não tem muito como fazer da forma como você está planejando. Tem algumas opções:

1. Alguns programadores tem a cultura de criar duas funções como você fez.
2. Outros criam uma passando um parâmetro que indica qual o operador será usado. Mas note que você não está passando o operador em si e sim algum indicador de qual operador deve ser usado. O parâmetro será um valor numérico, *string* ou algo específico. Dentro da função haverá um `if` para decidir de acordo com o parâmetro qual o código a ser executado.
3. Dependendo do seu caso é possível não se preocupar com o operador e mandar a informação pronta para qualquer caso, ou seja, você resolve a questão antes de chamar a função. Você manda como parâmetro o incremento ou decremento pronto. De acordo com as regras matemáticas, "mais com mais" dá "mais" e "mais com menos" dá menos", portanto dentro da função você só usa a adição.
4. Uma outra possibilidade nada recomendada é usar `eval()` para resolver isto. No fundo é uma variação do segundo caso mas neste caso não usaria o `if` e sim montaria a expressão como *string* e executaria ela. Coloquei só para mostrar caminhos variados. Esta opção tem problemas de performance, legibilidade dependendo do caso e segurança.

---

Como notas adicionais você pode simplificar o código atual da função e deixando ele apenas com uma linha:

```
imagem.src = arrayimgs[++count];
```

Assim você incrementa o contador antes de usar como índice do *array*.

Outro problema é que não é ideal acessar uma variável de fora da função, que tem [escopo global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32252/101). Faça o certo e passe o `count` como parâmetro e retorne ele incrementado. Vai lhe poupar problemas no futuro. Faça o mesmo com `arrayimgs` e `imagem`. Se é que realmente estas variáveis precisam existir fora desta função.

Já pensou porque você precisa acessar `imagemslide` com a função `getElementById('imagemslide');` e não acessa a variável direto? Você precisa minimizar a área de risco (este não é o único motivo para usar esta função). Desta forma poucas variáveis globais precisam ficar expostas. `document` é uma destas poucas variáveis.

[Estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101) de uma maneira geral é problemático. Casos como o `document` até faz algum sentido porque realmente é um objeto global para uma aplicação rodando em um navegador. Mesmo assim há quem diga que mesmo ela não deveria ser acessada de forma direta.

Provavelmente eu faria algo assim:

```
function rodarSlider(contador, rolagem) {
    var arrayimgs = ["js/img1.jpg","js/img2.jpg","js/img3.jpg"];
    var imagem = document.getElementById('imagemslide');
    imagem.src = arrayimgs[contador + rolagem];
    return contador;
}

algumContador = rodarSlider(algumContador, 1); //próximo
algumContador = rodarSlider(algumContador, -1); //anterior
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/Counter.js).

Seria algo assim porque na forma como está o seu código ele não parece fazer muito sentido.

---

Olhando o código que você postou depois no comentário me faz pensar que ter duas funções é a melhor solução neste caso. Dá para transformar em apenas uma função mas o código ficaria tão complicado que eu acho que não vale à pena. Duas funções ficaria mais legível.

Me parece que você está querendo economizar código à qualquer custo. Eu fiz muito isto quando estava aprendendo. E na época até fazia algum sentido, eu comecei programar em computador com 2KB de memória e qualquer *byte* economizado era fundamental mesmo em código que era interpretado. Mas com o tempo aprendi que legibilidade é melhor.

Claro que atentar ao princípio [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) é muito bom e ainda é um das coisas que mais busco. Mas demora para entender quando deve duplicar alguma coisa ou não. Às vezes duplicar melhora o código. E mesmo quando é melhor ter uma forma canônica isto precisa ser feito sem incorrer em outros erros com o uso de variáveis globais.

Usar funções auxiliares, mesmo que seja apenas para pegar uma valor de uma variável que guarda um valor de forma forma global ([estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101)), é uma da formas de canonizar um conhecimento da aplicação.

Comment: enquanto eu leio suas explicações eu não entendo nada. só quando eu vejo o exemplo, haha. de todo jeito vou arquivar as duas soluções. obrigado denovo man.

Comment: eu acho que deveria funcionar simplesmente passando o operador nos parenteses. deveria funcionar.

Comment: as variáveis são globais para serem usadas nas duas funções ou até em funções que eu possa fazer posteriormente.

Comment: è que você está começando, e está tentando fazer coisas um tento complexas. Tem que dar um passo de cada vez. Quando entender por completo os princípios da programação vai entender porque quase nenhuma linguagem permite passar um operador como parâmetro. É algo possível de fazer em uma linguagem, algumas fizeram, mas traz mais problemas que soluções. Não use variáveis globais. Eu nunca uso. Nunca! No máximo eu uso a mesma técnica do `getElementById`. Eu crio uma função que me retorna um valor que vou precisar em mais de um lugar. Isto é DRY seguro.

Comment: poderia iniciar chat?

Comment: tem como falar com vc inbox?