# Montar array através de uma lista em ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho uma função ajax que consome um webservice ,e me retorna uma lista, como pego essa lista e monto dois arrays com os valores?

JS:

```
function getCars() {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "CarService.asmx/GetAllCars",
  data: "MethodName=GetAllCars",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {

    //QUERO MONTAR OS ARRAYS AQUI 
    });
  },
  failure: function(msg) {
    $('#output').text(msg);
  }
});
```

}

Quero pegar o retorno dessa lista e montar dois arrays.
Ex: a lista retorna 5 registros, com ID,valor, e cor do carro.
Quero montar dois arrays, um para cor e outro para o valor Ex:

```
var cor = [];
var valor = [];
```

Quero preencher nele os 3 registros retornados na lista, ou seja, 3 cores e 3 valor, ficando

```
cor['red','blue','blue'] 
valor ['20.5','30.5','50.5']
```

Somente isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que o retorno do seu webservice seja algo do tipo:

```
response = [ 
 {"Id": 1, "Valor": "10.000", "Cor": "Azul"}, 
 {"Id": 2, "Valor": "15.000", "Cor": "Verde"}, 
 {"Id": 3, "Valor": "12.000", "Cor": "Vermelho"}
];
```

Utilize o método `push` para popular o array:

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    cor.push(item.Cor);
    valor.push(item.Valor);
});
```

Comment: esse i, é o indice? outra duvida, posso declarar os arrays fora da função pra ser ultilizada em qualquer outra?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Pode sim, dá uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32252/4622)! @WarLock

Comment: Obrigado lúcio, isso responde o meu outro toópico que acho que foi mal entendido, veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80970/grafico-highcharts-com-webservice responde lá, pois lá seria na prática, obg :)

Answer (score 2):

como alternativa ao método o Lucio, você também pode usar o map nativo do JavaScript, onde ele monta um array usando o retorno da função.

Note tambem que você pode continuar a manipular o array usando métodos nativos, como o sort (para ordenar) e o filter (para filtrar).

No exemplo abaixo uso o map para matar os dois arrays, logo apos o sort e o filter para ordenar as cores em ordem alfabética e remover as duplicações.

```js
response = [ 
  {ID: 1, Valor: 20.5, Cor: "red"}, 
  {ID: 2, Valor: 30.5, Cor: "blue"}, 
  {ID: 3, Valor: 50.5, Cor: "blue"}
]; 

var valor = response.map(function (item) { return item.Valor; });
var cor = response.map(function (item) { return item.Cor; });
var filtro = cor.sort().filter(function (item, indice) { return cor.indexOf(item) == indice; });

console.log(filtro);
```

Comment: Muito bom! :) @TobyMosque