# Angular não reconhece uma variável de fora do controle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope

Eu to com uma dúvida, já procurei em outros fóruns e não achei a solução.
Fiz um teste no um código abaixo apenas para demonstração.

```
*//dentro do controle do angular*
angular.module("NaBalada").controller("NaBaladaLocal", function(data){
    return $scope.teste = 'Testando Angular';
    console.log(testejs)
});
*//Script normal JS*
console.log(teste);*//teste do $scope.teste*
let testejs = 'Variável fora do angular, pra reconhecer dentro do controller'
```

então o meu problema é esse fazer com que as variáveis seja vista dentro e fora, para que possa receber algum valor na minha aplicação, o erro que aparece é 'teste is not defined' e 'testejs is not defined'

Alguém pode me ajudar, desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Por qual motivo você quer usar fora? creio eu que elas funcionaram muito bem dentro do controller, além disso se você fosse usar algum elemento fora do escopo 'NaBaladaLocal', você teria de declarar outro controller e compartilhar informações entre eles.

Comment: Eu to utilizando uma biblioteca para gerar poligonos e tive que fazer isso fora do angular, e para inserir no meu banco de dados que utilizar o $http.post do angular.. mas pra isso tenho que fazer com que o angular reconheça as variáreis que estão no meu script js.

Comment: Entendi, você está usando uma variável global oque é muito perigoso kk, recomendo que leia isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32251/vari%C3%A1vel-global-em-javascript

Comment: Então, eu dei uma olhada, mas mesmo assim não consegui realizar o que eu queria.Acho que a melhor forma de eu tentar esclarecer o funcionamento seria, a onde tem //script normal JS; Compare ele como um segundo arquivo. a primeira parte `teste1.js` e a segunda parte `teste.js` que carregam em um mesmo `index.html`. mas quando declaro por exemplo `var tst2 = "Teste"` quando digo `console.log(tst2)` dentro do meu controller do angular ele não reconhece. e dá o que já informei na pergunta. :/

Answer (score 1):

No seu código, você está interrompendo a execução da função *antes* de imprimir o conteúdo:

```
angular.module("NaBalada").controller("NaBaladaLocal", function(data){
    return $scope.teste = 'Testando Angular';
    console.log(testejs)
});
```

Nada é processado após a palavra-chave `return`, que finaliza a execução da função. Tente a seguinte alteração:

```
angular.module("NaBalada").controller("NaBaladaLocal", function(data){
    console.log(testejs);
    $scope.teste = 'Testando Angular';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver de uma forma, ainda não sei se é a forma correta apenas para eu capturar um geojson e jogar no meu banco de dados, utilizei da seguinte forma e funcionou.

```
*//dentro do controle do angular*
angular.module("NaBalada").controller("NaBaladaLocal", function(){
    window.teste = 'Testando Angular';
    console.log(testejs);
});

*//Script normal JS*
console.log(teste);*//teste do $scope.teste*
window.testejs = 'Variável fora do angular, pra reconhecer dentro do controller'
```

Vou deixar ai, pode ser que isso ajude alguém.

Comment: Veja a resposta do OnoSendai, ela vai te orientar melhor sobre o problema, o que causou e como resolver.

Comment: Obrigado, se puder ler nos comentários acima que fiz com o Felipe Duarte pode entender melhor.