# Como acessar o valor de uma variável em blocos de função diferentes em javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis

Estou tentando acessar o valor de um variável chamado média dentro de um bloco de função diferente  de onde ela foi declarada porém não consigo.

minha função para pegar os valores em Alerta() eu tenho comportamento esperado: eu pego os valores e ele exibe o a média correta

```
function Alerta() { <br>
 var nota1 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite a nota 1")); <br>
 var nota2 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite a nota 2"));  <br>
 var nota3 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite a nota 3")); <br>
 var media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3  <br>
 alert("A media é " + media); <br>
}
```

porém, quando tento acessar média dentro da função Aprovado()
ela só me retorna reprovado mesmo que a nota seja maior que 7.

```
function Aprovado() {  <br>
  if (media > 7)  <br>
  alert("Aprovado");  <br>
  else  <br>
    alert("Reprovado"); <br>
}
```

Comment: deveria declarar a variável fora das funções, por exemplo `var media = 0; function Alerta() ..... function Aprovado()....`

Comment: isso seria uma solução simples para resolver o sua duvida, isso se chama variável global, uma melhor forma seria passar o valor de media como parâmetro, leia mais aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32251/vari%c3%a1vel-global-em-javascript

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo declarar a variável fora da função resolveu

Comment: Não precisa de variável global e nem da complicação desnecessária da resposta abaixo (que para um caso simples como esse eu achei exagero, mas claro que tem os seus usos). Basta que uma função retorne a média, que por sua vez será passada como argumento para a outra função: https://jsfiddle.net/3q1ghw2f/

Answer (score -3):

Empacotando tudo em um módulo, esse é o conceito de "module pattern". A ideia é que ele é autocontido.

```
var calculaMedia = (function () {
    var media;
    return {
        obtemNotas: function () {
            var nota1 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite a nota 1"));
            var nota2 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite a nota 2"));
            var nota3 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite a nota 3"));
            media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;
            alert("A media é " + media);
        },
        aprovado: function () {
            if (media > 7)
                alert("Aprovado");
            else
                alert("Reprovado");
        }
    };
})();

calculaMedia.obtemNotas();
calculaMedia.aprovado();
```

Comment: Gostei muito do seu código, mas como resposta possui alguns problemas. Sua resposta não responde a duvida apresentada na pergunta que é como a partir da estrutura proposta obter o valor de uma varável declarada em outro escopo, seria bom inicialmente com o próprio código do AP mostrar como obter o resultado esperado, então explicar quais as desvantagens da abordagem usada pelo AP, então o contextualizar e mostrar as vantagens sobre uso de design patterns e padrão module pattern para ai então chegar a sua solução proposta. Uma boa explicação agrega muito valor a resposta.