# Resposta de ajax repete a de outra requisição e a página nem é a mesma

Tags: javascript, ajax

O cenário é o seguinte: tenho um ajax que fica esperando resposta do servidor em Java na porta 2336 igual ao Hotmail, e, assim que tem atualização, o Java retorna resposta e fecha a requisição HTTP aberta. Depois o javascript pega a resposta e executa o que quer que seja e abre novamente outra requisição para esperar novamente por novas atualizações. Quando eu tenho que mandar alguma coisa para o servidor eu mando para o PHP pra porta 80, normalmente em outra requisição, e o PHP retorna a resposta se foi bem sucedido ou não. Até ai tudo OK, o problema é que se a requisição de sincronia com o Java na porta 2336 está aberta e eu mando alguma coisa para a porta 80 quando chega algum aviso de autalização do Java a resposta é a mesma da do PHP. Em seguida, se eu não tiver enviado nada para o PHP novamente, mostra a resposta do Java normalmente.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

As funções são as seguintes:

```
function sincronizar() {
    ajax("http://" + window.location.hostname + ":2336", "POST", "Id=Anderson", executaResposta, "");
}

function controle() {
    ajax("php/controle.php", "POST", "Comando=ID", "containerFiltragemEntregas", "");
}

function ajax(endereco, metodo, dados, alvo, distracao) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (distracao != "") {
        centralizaElemento(distracao);
        mostraElemento(distracao);
    }
    if (typeof(alvo) == "string") {
        elemento(alvo).innerHTML = "";
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var retorno = xmlhttp.responseText.trim();
            mostraAlerta(retorno + "\r\n\r\n" + metodo);
            if (typeof(alvo) == "function") {
                alvo(retorno);
                } else {
                    elemento(alvo).innerHTML = retorno;
            }
            if (distracao != "") {
                centralizaElemento(distracao);
                escondeElemento(distracao, 2000);
            }
        }
    }

    if (metodo == "GET") {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", endereco + "?" + dados, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } else if (metodo == "POST") {
        xmlhttp.open("POST", endereco, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(dados);
    }
}

function executaResposta(resposta) {
    var respostaSeparada = resposta.split("|");
    var comandoSeparado;
    if (respostaSeparada[0] == "01") {
        if (respostaSeparada[1] == "01") {
            comandoSeparado = respostaSeparada[3].split("&");
            if (respostaSeparada[2] == "05") {
                alertaEntrega("containerEntrega" + comandoSeparado[0]);
            } else if (respostaSeparada[2] == "04") {
                escondeElemento("containerEntrega" + comandoSeparado[0]);
            } else {
                normalizaEntrega("containerEntrega" + comandoSeparado[0]);
            }
            elemento("entregaSituacao" + comandoSeparado[0]).innerHTML = comandoSeparado[1];
        }
     }
    sincronizar();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que você usa um único objeto XMLHttpRequest. Eu posso estar errado, mas acho que para corrigir bastar tornar a sua variável `xmlhttp` local (pois ela é uma [global implícita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2513/74)):

```
function ajax(endereco, metodo, dados, alvo, distracao) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // ... O resto fica igual
}
```

Assim, cada chamada de `ajax` vai criar uma variável `xmlhttp` independente, e as requisições não vão interferir umas nas outras.

Comment: Era isto mesmo, sei que não é pra agradecer aqui mas resolveu o problema!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar :)