# Instanciar uma função global padrão para chamar funções

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como posso criar uma variável global (ou elemento global, não sei como chama) como em vários plugins que vejo. Exemplo no Jquery onde para chamar qualquer função referente a ele só tenho que instanciar o símbolo `#` ou chamar pela função `Jquery` antes de qualquer função interna do plugin.

Quero que em minha aplicação eu consiga chamar algo do tipo:

```
MeuElemento.Cria(args);
MeuElemento.Salvar(args);
MeuElemento.Outrafunção(args);
```

Como faço isso? Alguém por favor me consegue um exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta criar um objeto global e adicionar funções a ele.

Quando você faz um objeto global, como abaixo, ele fica visível... Bem, globalmente.

```
var foo = {}; // foo só será global se essa linha rodar no escopo global, ok?
```

Agora é só adicionar funções ou o que mais você quiser. Você pode fazer isso a qualquer momento, pois os objetos em Javascript podem receber novas propriedades e métodos dinamicamente.

```
foo.monstraUmPopup = function (args) {
    alert(args);
}
```

E você pode chamar globalmente também:

```
foo.mostraUmPopup("tio");
```

Experimente no console do seu navegador.

Comment: Eu não recomendaria omitir o `var`. Melhor usá-lo, certificando-se de que a variável está sendo declarada no escopo global. Acho menos confuso.

Comment: muito obrigado, vai ficar bem mais organizado meu código rs

Comment: @bfavaretto Não usar `var` força a variável a ficar no escopo global, mas tens razão quanto a ser menos confuso com `var`. Vou editar.

Comment: Eu sei que força, mas sempre acho bom recomendar nunca omitir :) Já falei disso aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2517/74. PS: obrigado pelo edit