# É possível atribuir laço de repetição a uma variável?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramação

Estou implementando um código onde se caso a variável recebida não contenha um valor deve ser feito um `for`, caso contrário, não.

Bem, se fosse para o caso "simples", era só implementar os `if` com as condições e montar o `for` conforme o resultado, mas assim ficaria muito grande o código. Por isso gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o seguinte trecho no JavaScript.

```
<script language="javascript">
w_valor_1;
w_valor_2;

if(w_valor_1 == ""){
   w_for_1 = "for(i = 0; i < w_b; i++){";
   w_ch_1 = "}";
}
else{
   i = w_valor_1;
   w_for_1 = "";
}
if(w_valor_2 == ""){
   w_for_2 = "for(j = 0; j < w_c; j++){";
   w_ch_2 = "}";
}
else{
   j = w_valor_2;
   w_for_2 = "";
}

w_for_1;
w_for_2;
   m_valores[i][j] = b++;
w_ch_2;
w_ch_1;

</script>
```

Comment: Imagino que a solução seja utilizar o [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, lendo o que você passou sobre o eval me surgiu uma dúvida. Com ele é possível realizar o `for`? Ele iteraria normalmente? Como montar com ele se fosse esse meu caso? Desculpa, são muitas perguntas e.e'

Comment: Na verdade, vendo melhor o seu código, não consegui entender onde você inicializa w_b e w_c, mas o que eu faria seria inicializar ambos com zero e só alteraria o valor deles, caso w_valor_1 e w_valor_2, fossem diferentes de "" respectivamente.

Comment: No caso de `w_b` e `w_c` eles vem do `PHP`, onde contém um valor de uma página anterior podendo conter valores de 1...n!

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, é possível montar com o eval? Se sim, conseguiria me mostrar um exemplo com o código que mostrei?' Obrigado!

Comment: O @mgibsonbr já mostrou como, além de dar uma solução melhor que utilizando o eval, que é um pouco mais lento. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha sugestão é simplesmente ajustar os limites do `for` para executar apenas uma vez caso a variável esteja definida, ou N vezes caso não esteja:

```
for( var i = (w_valor_1 === "" ?   0 : w_valor_1  ) ; 
         i < (w_valor_1 === "" ? w_b : w_valor_1+1) ; i++)
    for( var j = (w_valor_2 === "" ?   0 : w_valor_2  ) ; 
             j < (w_valor_2 === "" ? w_c : w_valor_2+1) ; j++)
        m_valores[i][j] = b++;
```

P.S. Não se esqueça de [sempre usar `var` antes das variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2513/215), senão elas viram globais...

Mas apenas para referência, eis o que você precisaria fazer caso decidisse usar o `eval`:

```
eval(w_for_1 + w_for_2 + "m_valores[i][j] = b++;" + w_ch_2 + w_ch_1);
```

(lembrando que o `w_ch_1` e `w_ch_2` *também* precisariam receber `""` dentro do `else`)