# Criar variável à partir de string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suponhamos que eu tenha:

```
var develop = 'confirmName1'
```

E quero criar uma nova variável à partir do valor da *variável develop ("confirmName1"):*

```
var 'confirmName1' = 'valorDaNovaVariavel'

alert(confrirmName); // Retornar: (String) valorDaNovaVariavel
```

Em *PHP* eu sei, mas aparentemente não funciona do mesmo jeito em *JavaScript*.

Comment: Não é o nome da variável com o valor da outra, no caso criar uma variável com o nome confirmName1

Comment: ficou confuso o modo como descreveu.. mas dá para entender.. apesar disso, basta corrigir ao invés de colocar no comentario..

Comment: falando tecnicamente, o termo mais proximo ao equivalente no PHP seria "variável variável". É usar o valor de uma variável para nomear outra variável.

Comment: Considerando o que você postou mais abaixo como resposta (não é uma resposta, e por isso já foi apagado de lá), acho melhor você [postar uma nova pergunta](/questions/ask) e nela colocar mais detalhes do que você precisa fazer e por que está querendo usar esse método. Provavelmente tem alternativas melhores do que as sugestões de `eval` e variáveis globais – que respondem a esta pergunta da maneira como está formulada, mas podem e devem ser evitados na maioria dos casos.

Comment: **Observação:** Todas as respostas estão equivocadas, elas [ensinam uma prática a ser evitada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2513/137387) e errado. O acesso ao escopo global exigi uma sintaxe diferente em diferentes ambientes JavaScript, em páginas de navegadores o objeto global é `window`, em contexto de Web Workers o objeto global é `this`, em Denojs e Nodejs o objeto global é `global`. Para fornecer uma maneira padrão de acessar o objeto global entre ambientes existe a propriedade [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma técnica que você pode fazer isso. É mais ou menos assim:

```
var x = "nome"; 
eval("var " + x + " = 'Tonho';");
console.log("Valor da variável nome:", nome);
```

Como pode ver acima, a função que faz a "mágica" se chama **eval**, porém há uma série de restrições que o uso de função, principalmente quando se trata de segurança...

> Não use eval desnecessariamente! eval() é uma função perigosa, que
>   executa o código passado com os privilégios do caller. Se você
>   executar o eval() com uma seqüência de caracteres que podem ser
>   afetados por uma pessoa maliciosa, você pode acabar executando código
>   malicioso na máquina do usuário com as permissões da sua
>   página/extensão. Mais importante ainda, o código de terceiros pode ver
>   o escopo em que eval() foi chamado, o que pode levar a possíveis
>   ataques como  Function não é susceptível.

Conheça a função por completo aqui:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

**### ATUALIZANDO ###**

Há uma forma mais "limpa" e mais segura de se fazer isso. Veja:

```js
var x = "nome";
window[x] = "Tonho";
document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = "Valor da variável nome: " + nome;
```

```html
<h3 id="resultado"></h3>
```

É importante ressaltar que a variável criada dinamicamente estará no escopo global da aplicação.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

Segue um exemplo simples:

```js
var chave = 'valor';

window[chave] = 'valor';

document.write(valor); // valor = valor
```

Answer (score 1):

Exitem maneiras diferentes de escrever isto amigo.

Se você trabalha com o conceito de telas, eu sugiro algo semelhante a isso:

```
var tela = document.body;
var nameVar = "somar";
tela[nameVar] =  3.14 * 3.14;

//mais codigo e bla bla bla..
console.log("resultado", tela.somar);

//tambem pode recuperar o valor da var assim:
console.log("valor da var", tela[nameVar]);
```