# Controle de variavel com Javascript para html

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um código HTML com JavaScript que ao clicar em cima;
Se `x == 1`, executa tarefa `A` e seta variável javascript `x = 0`, senão, executa tarefa `B` e seta variável javascript `x = 1`, porém a variável é reiniciada sempre que inciada a função.

**Como resolver ?**

JavaScript:

```
function toogle_m(MID, PID) {
    if(x == 1) {
        alert("Luck 7!"+"x");
        var x = 0;
    } else {
        alert("You're not very locky today..."+"x");
        var x = 1;
    }

    $(MID).fadeToggle(500);
    $(PID).hide();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="F1" onclick="toogle_m(del)">
    <img src='resources/images/andremachado/del.png' width='25' title='Excluir insumos'/>
</div>
```

Sei que vai reiniciar por que é iniciada a função sempre, mas qual a solução ?

Comment: já tentou transformar a variavel em global ?

Comment: **Leitura Recomendada** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu problema está no escopo em que a variável foi declarada. Se declaras uma variável dentro da função, seu tempo de vida vai ser equivalente ao da função. Uma maneira de contornar isto é declarando a variável fora da função, ficará assim:

```
// Inicializa com 0.
var x = 0;

function toogle_m(MID, PID) {
    if(x == 1) {
        alert("Luck 7!"+"x");
        x = 0;
    } else {
        alert("You're not very locky today..."+"x");
        x = 1;
    }

    $(MID).fadeToggle(500);
    $(PID).hide();
}
```

Comment: Tentei como falou e não deu, tambem fiz outro codigo com o mesmo pensamento e só retorna o primeiro if:

var foo = 0;
function toogle_m(MID,PID){
    if (foo != 0) { 
        alert("Lucky 7!"+"x");
        var foo = 0;
    }
    else{
        alert("You're not very lucky today..."+"x"); 
    var foo = 1;
    }

        $( MID ).fadeToggle(500);
        $( PID ).hide();
}

Comment: @AndréSilveiraMachado certeza que fez certo? por que o código que você postou aqui no comentário não está certo, preste atenção no código da resposta, quando entra no `if` eu declaro o valor à variável `x` declarada fora da função, no exemplo comentado você cria uma variável nova e atribui o valor, não atribui à variável externa.

Comment: Obrigado, retirei o var do lado e funcionou, desculpe, seu código estava correto!

Answer (score 3):

Tenta isso, tornando X sua variável global.

```
var foo = 0;
function toogle_m(){
    if (foo == 1) { 
        alert("Lucky 7!"+"x");
    foo = 0;
  }
  else{
    alert("You're not very lucky today..."+"x"); 
    foo = 1;
  }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.F1').click(function(){
      toogle_m();      
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div class="F1">
    <img src='resources/images/andremachado/del.png' width='25' title='Excluir insumos'/>
</div>
```

Exemplo

[jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/tbbb5d2L/)

Comment: Tentei como falou e não deu, tambem fiz outro codigo com o mesmo pensamento e só retorna o primeiro if:

var foo = 0;
function toogle_m(MID,PID){
    if (foo != 0) { 
        alert("Lucky 7!"+"x");
        var foo = 0;
    }
    else{
        alert("You're not very lucky today..."+"x"); 
    var foo = 1;
    }

        $( MID ).fadeToggle(500);
        $( PID ).hide();
}

Comment: para de usar var foo em todo lugar, deixa o var foo global e depois dentro do metodo use apenas foo, sem o var.

http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/tbbb5d2L/2/

Comment: Obrigado, retirei o var do lado e funcionou!

Comment: Da joinha e coloca a minha resp como correta, isso me ajuda com a pontuação!" ;)