# Como evitar que um plugin entre em conflito?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Estou escrevendo um plugin para tabelas chamado [easyTable](https://github.com/Gabrielr47/easyTable).

Depois de entender o funcionamento básico de um plugin e como ele pode realizar um encadeamento li na documentação que para evitar o conflito ele deveria ficar assim:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.easyTable = function() {
        // methods...
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Gostaria de entender por que o plugin deve estar dentro desta função,pelo que parece isto a torna anônima.

Documentação: [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: Me parece que você está confundindo o que rola, esse modelo não vai prevenir conflitos no seu plugin, ou seja, se houver outro jquery plugin chamado `easyTable` ainda vai conflitar. O que o modelo previne é o conflito entra a jQuery lib e outra lib que use `$` (sendo ainda necessário que você invoque [`noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)), a resposta do [bfavaretto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117489/21328) explica como isso funciona.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que torna a função anônima é que ela não tem nome :) Veja só:

```
(function ( $ ) {
```

Cadê o nome? Não tem, logo é uma função anônima. Os parênteses em volta são necessários por um detalhe de sintaxe (se a linha começa com `function`, a função precisa ter nome). Mais detalhes sobre isso nesta outra pergunta: [Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function() e function name()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-var-name-function-e-function-name)

Os motivos para o plugin estar dentro da função anônima:

1. Todas as variáveis que você criar, [com `var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript), dentro da função anônima não irão ficar disponíveis globalmente. Isso é bom, o código do seu plugin fica encapsulado e não arrisca interferir com outros scripts presentes na página.
2. A função anônima é imediatamente invocada (repare no `( jQuery )`) no final), e recebe como argumento o objeto `jQuery`. Somente dentro da função esse objeto está disponível como `$`. Assim, seu plugin pode se referir ou jQuery como `$` sem correr o risco de se referir a outra biblioteca que também utilize o identificador `$` – por exemplo, o [prototype](http://prototypejs.org).

Comment: Mas e se todas as variaveis criadas forem dentro do  do plugin não have a necessidade  de usar isto, por que elas pertencem apenas ao escopo do plugin, ou está errado ?

Comment: Correto, se tudo for declarado dentro da função atribuída ao `$.fn.easyTable`, fica tudo restrito a esse escopo. Nesse caso, você só perde a prevenção de conflitos entre o jQuery e outras bibliotecas (ver [comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117484/como-evitar-que-um-plugin-entre-em-conflito#comment245296_117484) do BrunoRB acima).

Comment: +1,Agora entendi, no meu caso irei declarar apenas para prevenir conflitos com outras bibliotecas.

Answer (score 2):

Pois fazendo isso você cria um escopo local e toda e qualquer `var` ou `function` que você cria pertence unicamente a este local, você tera acesso o espaço global de fora, mas o espaço de fora não tera acesso ao seu local - a menos que você diga que a variável é global.

Isso é conhecido como encapsulamento.

[Modularização em JavaScript](http://tableless.com.br/modularizacao-em-javascript/)
[Quando se deve usar var no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript/93713#93713)

Comment: +1, entendi, vou ler estes artigos!