# Qual é a finalidade do comando var quando utilizado na declaração de funções?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Em JavaScript é possível escrever funções com ou sem a utilização da palavra chave `var`, veja abaixo duas funções que ilustram esta situação:

```js
var soma = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

window.alert("Soma de 10 + 5 eh igual a: " + soma(10, 5));

subtrai = function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

window.alert("Subtracao de 20 - 10 eh igual a: " + subtrai(20, 10));
```

Perceba que a função `soma()` utiliza a palavra chave `var` e a função `subtrai()` não a utiliza. Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade da utilização da palavra chave `var` quando é utilizada na declarações de funções e se a utilização dela ou não implica em algo?

Comment: [Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function e function name?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/91)

Comment: @rray não havia percebido rsrs.

Comment: Note que esse segundo caso é diferente de fazer `function subtrai` - ambos os exemplos criam uma função anônima e a atribuem a uma variável. A diferença é que no segundo caso a variável `subtrai` é **global**, pois foi criada sem o uso do `var`. Mais informações [nessa outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2513/215).