# Quando eu clico na id de referencia da tag não chama a pagina que eu quero

Tags: javascript, html

Não consigo fazer funcionar de forma alguma...me ajudem por gentileza!

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("ClicouNaTag").addEventListener(
        "click",function() {
            window.location.href = "vaiparaessapagina.php";
        }
    );  
</script>
```

Comment: A página fica na raiz? Porque, quando você usa `vaiparaessapagina.php`, se você estiver num caminho que tenha "sub paths" na url, ele vai alterar só o último path.

Comment: Exemplo, se você fazer `location.href = 'index.php'` em uma página assim: `exemplo.com/teste/teste`, ele vai redirecionar assim `exemplo.com/teste/index.php`. Confirme para nós.

Comment: Sim. Está, nada acontece...continua na mesma pagina...experimentei colocar um alerta e assim o alerta entra e mostra a mensagem, mas a pagina continua no index.php

Comment: Já conferiu as requisições no console?

Comment: Observe:

<li class="nav-item"><a id="ClicouNaTag" class="nav-link" href="index.php"><em class="fa fa-address-card"></em>Vaiparaessapagina</a>

Comment: Emilio, será que não é porque você já tem um `href` na tag que você está colocando a ação? Adicione esse trecho à pergunta.

Comment: Wallace Maxters pode me ajudar a fazer essas consultas no console? Eu não sei...eu apenas vejo que a página ainda é o index.html no caminho do browser

Comment: dê uma olhada na minha resposta, jovem. Vê se isso te ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Autor da Pergunta informou que tem o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a id="ClicouNaTag" class="nav-link" href="index.php">
        <em class="fa fa-address-card"></em>Vaiparaessapagina</a>
```

O código para mudança de página é o seguinte:

```
document.getElementById("ClicouNaTag").addEventListener(
    "click",function() {
        window.location.href = "vaiparaessapagina.php";
    }
);
```

O problema é que o elemento `a#ClicouNaTag` tem o atributo `href` que faz com que o redirecionamento seja feito para a própria página. Assim, esse redirecionamento vai impedir que o evento `click` seja processado.

É importante lembrar que, em muitos casos onde se usa captura dos eventos no Javascript, deve-se impedir a ação padrão do elemento através do método `event.preventDefault()`.

Altere seu código para:

```
document.getElementById("ClicouNaTag").addEventListener(
    "click",function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "vaiparaessapagina.php";
    }
);
```

E, já que não vai usar o `href="index.php"`, eu substituiria esse trecho por `#` ou por `javascript: void(0)`.

Assim:

```
 <a id="ClicouNaTag" class="nav-link" href="#">...
```

Comment: Não deu certo. E veja aqui o código:

<li class="nav-item">      
<a id="ClicouAqui" class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
</li>

<script>
    document.getElementById("ClicouAqui").addEventListener(
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("You clicked aqui");
            window.location.href = "vaiparaessapagina.php";
            );
</script>

Não funciona de modo algum. O ALERTA funciona mas não vai para a pagina de forma nenhuma.

Comment: Pessoal, Obrigado! Eu consegui...

Ainda penso em outra dúvida: tenho uma variavel global, posso altera-la dentro do javascript?

document.getElementById("ClicouNaTag").addEventListener(
    "click",function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        **varGloal = '1';**
        window.location.href = "vaiparaessapagina.php";
    }
);

Comment: @EmilioDamiSilva se for o caso, faça outra pergunta, mas pode sim. Pra alterar uma variável global, basta declará-la fora do escopo da função com `var`e dentro da função atribuir um valor a ela, sem declarar com var).

Comment: @EmilioDamiSilva recomendo essa leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript

Comment: Obrigado @Wallace Maxters
Eu ainda não sei como dar nota nas respostas, mas é 10!!!!!!!
Obrigado!!!!